# When to use std::vector<unsigned char> vs. std::vector<char>

Tags: c++, stdvector

Which of one of these is best suited for managing a character buffer that can be easily converted to std::string and passed to and used ( i.e. read / write ) in C functions

```
std::vector<unsigned char> 
std::vector<char>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`char`'s signedness depends on the compiler.<sup>1</sup>

It can represent a `unsigned char` or `signed char`. Which type is used when representing a `string` is dependent on the compiler - therefore you should use `char` for portability, and clarity. If that isn't enough, would the less typing needed when writing `char` convince you? :)

Again, the compiler thinks `string`s are of type `char *`, which can be equivalent to `unsigned char *` or `signed char *`. If you're going to be working with `string`s use `std::vector<char>`.

<sup>1</sup> `char` is the only type with this behavior.

---

#### References

> <sup>1</sup> [Is char signed or unsigned by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2054939/char-is-signed-or-unsigned-by-default/2054941#2054941)

Answer (score 2):

`char` is more compatible with strings than `unsigned char`. String literals are `char[]` and `std::string` is actually `std::basic_string<char>`.

Comment: In what way could unsigned char not be compatible with strings? In other words can you illustrate for me what could go wrong if I use unsigned char to represent strings? I am not disputing your answer I just want to get a better understanding

Comment: @karimjee : `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`; `std::basic_string<>` relies on `std::char_traits<>`, but `std::char_traits<>` is only specialized for `char` and `wchar_t`. So, `std::basic_string<>` will not **portably** play nice with `unsigned char` out of the box (though in practice, it will work just fine with most modern compilers).

Comment: @ildjarn: you posted the best answer to the OP's original question

Answer (score 0):

Both are equally well suited. If these are character buffers, as opposed to bytes, I would go with std::vector< char >.

You can create a string from a vector of any of those types with std::string( v.begin(), b.end() );

Answer (score 0):

`char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are 3 distinct types.

- Use an `unsigned char` or a `signed char` when dealing with numbers.
- Use a regular `char` when dealing with strings.

Thus, you should use a `char`.